# Leer Datos desde Arduino-Bluetooth a Android Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic4, bluetooth

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de Ionic Capacitor para comunicarme con un arduino desde mi celular, la comunicación es mediante bluetooth. He instalado el plugin BluetoothSerial y logré mandar datos desde mi aplicación de celular hacia el arduino (el arduino recepciona datos por medio del modulo bluetooth HC-05).

El problema que tengo es que no sé como implementar la parte de código para leer los datos que envío desde Arduino. En la documentación de https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial (plugin BluetoothSerial) tengo los métodos bluetoothSerial.subscribe() y bluetoothSerial.read() que me servirían para leer los datos que envío desde Arduino, pero no tengo claro donde colocarlos en mi codigo de tal forma que pueda recibir datos de Arduino en mi app de forma asincrónica.
¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Tengo implementado los sgtes código:

home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { BluetoothSerial } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/bluetooth-serial/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  pairedList: any[];
  listToggle: boolean = false;
  pairedDevice: number = 0;
  dataSend: string = "";
  dataRead: string = "";

  constructor(private bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial, private toastCtrl: ToastController) {
    this.checkBluetooth()
  }

  checkBluetooth(){
    this.bluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then(success=>{
      this.showError("Bluetooth activado");

    },error=>{
      this.showError("Por favor, activar bluetooth ")
    })
  }

  pairedListDevice(){
    this.bluetoothSerial.list().then(success=>{
      this.pairedList = success;
      this.listToggle = true;
    },error=>{
      this.showError("Por favor, activar bluetooth ");
      this.listToggle = false;
    })
  }

  selectDevice() {
    let connectedDevice = this.pairedList[this.pairedDevice];
    if (!connectedDevice.address) {
      this.showError('Select Paired Device to connect');
      return;
    }
    let address = connectedDevice.address;
    let name = connectedDevice.name;

    this.connect(address);
  }

  connect(address) {
    // Attempt to connect device with specified address, call app.deviceConnected if success
    this.bluetoothSerial.connect(address).subscribe(success => {
      this.deviceConnected();
      this.showError("Successfully Connected");
    }, error => {
      this.showError("Error:Connecting to Device");
    });
  }

  deviceConnected() {
    // Subscribe to data receiving as soon as the delimiter is read
    this.bluetoothSerial.subscribe('\n').subscribe(success => {
      this.handleData(success);
      this.showError("Connected Successfullly");
    }, error => {
      this.showError(error);
    });
  }

  deviceDisconnected() {
    // Unsubscribe from data receiving
    this.bluetoothSerial.disconnect();
    this.showError("Device Disconnected");
  }

  handleData(data) {
    this.showError(data);
  }

  sendData() {
    this.dataSend+='\n';
    this.showError(this.dataSend);

    this.bluetoothSerial.write(this.dataSend).then(success => {
      this.showError(success);
    }, error => {
      this.showError(error)
    });
  }
  
  readData(){
    this.bluetoothSerial.read().then((data) =>{
      this.dataRead += data;
    })
  }
  async showError(message) {
    const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: message,
      duration: 2000
    });
    toast.present();
  }
  
  
}

interface pairedList{
  "class": number;
  "id": string,
  "address": string,
  "name": string
}
```

Mi home.page.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-button color="dark" (click)="pairedListDevice()"><ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon>&nbsp;Refresh Bluetooth Devices</ion-button>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="pairedDevice" *ngIf="listToggle">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let i of pairedList;let j=index">
          <ion-label>{{i.name}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="{{j}}" ></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
    <ion-button color="medium" *ngIf="listToggle" (click)="selectDevice()"><ion-icon name="bluetooth"></ion-icon>&nbsp;Connect Bluetooth Devices<ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>&nbsp;Send Data Via Bluetooth</ion-button>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Type The Data You want to Send</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" name="datasend" [(ngModel)]="dataSend"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-button color="medium" (click)="sendData()"><ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>&nbsp;Send Data Via Bluetooth</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: quizas te sirva https://como-programar.net/ionic/bluetooth/

Comment: // the success callback is called whenever data is received
bluetoothSerial.subscribe('\n', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}, failure);-->http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/don/bluetoothserial

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47017533/8957405

Comment: Si podes proba este codigo entiemdo que con Observables funcionaria y subcribe('\n') retorna aun observables deviceConnected() {
    this.bluetoothSerial.subscribe('\n') .subscribe({
      
       next(succes) { console.log('got value ' + succes); },
       error(err) { console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err); },
        
       complete() { console.log('done'); }
        
      
     });
    }

Answer (score 0):

Yo crearía un servicio para gestionar la fuente de datos. En dicho servicio gestionaría todo lo concerniente al socket bluetooth.
Dentro del servicio devolvería observables para subscribirme a la lectura de los datos.
Los datos para que se actualicen en la vista hay que meterlos en el ngZone.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/337838)